# How to recalculate DB records IDs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Let us have some model in Rails application, represented by set of DB records. Each of them will have an 'id' field. If we delete a few first records, the `Model.first` method will return Model with `id > 0`.

So, the question is: how to update all the records in DB (in 'Rails style') to have records with the `id` field, starting from zero?

Comment: it is very expensive operation for big tables to update all records. And I don't know cases when it is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id field should not carry an information value. If you want the records to have numbers starting from 0, just add 'number' field and a unique index on that field.

Edit: This is the "Rails way" how to do it.

Comment: Actually I think this is a very dangerous and "not-railsy" operation that I would have to have a really good reason to do.